# Подсчет суммы длин между пунктами на графе

Tags: python, графы

сделал программу, которая считает количество путей на графе из точки 1 в точку N через точку M. Попробовал изменить ее чтобы вместо количества путей считалось расстояние, но у меня не вышло. Расстояние между точками всегда = 1. Граф ориентированный. Начав движение из какого-либо пункта, невозможно вернуться назад в тот же пункт. Может ли кто-то предложить свое решение для данной задачи, чтобы вместо количества путей считалось **сумма длин** путей?

N - количество городов
M - количество дорог.
Далее вводятся сами дороги, например, дорога из 1 города во город 2 записывается как 1 2

Программа ниже считает количество путей

```
def ways(start,end,karta,zapret):
    if start in zapret: return 0
    if start==end: return 1
    r=0
    for i in range(len(karta[start])):
        r += ways(karta[start][i],end,karta,zapret)
    return r

a = {}
n,m = map(int, input().split())
for i in range(m):
    start, end = map(int, input().split())     #Делаю словарь 
                                             #(ключ - город, значение - в какие города можно попасть из города start
    if str(start) in a.keys():
        s = str(end)
        d_elements = a.get(str(start))
        if int(s) > int(d_elements):
            s = str(d_elements) + s
        else:
            s += str(d_elements)
        del a[str(start)]
        a[str(start)] = s
    else:
        a[str(start)] = str(end)
    sorted_a = sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
    a = dict(sorted_a)

for i in range(1,n+1):
    print((ways('1',str(n),a, '') - ways('1',str(n),a,str(i))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполняете два поиска в ширину или глубину. Один из вершины 1 до вершины M, второй из вершины M до вершины N.

При поиске передаёте аргумент - пройденное расстояние от начала поиска, на следующий уровень передавать расстояние+1.

Нашли целевую вершину - в общий результат добавляете пройденный путь.

Примерно так (учитывая, что граф по условию ацикличен):

```
def ways(start,end,karta, distance):
    if start==end: 
        global summa
        summa += distance
        return 
    for i in range(len(karta[start])):
        ways(karta[start][i],end,karta,distance+1)
```

Comment: а вы можете, пожалуйста, написать саму функцию для этого решения, не понимаю как нужно делать поиск в ширину и глубину?

Comment: Так ваше waуs - это поиск в ширину